# formula to limit date entries to specific month

Tags: list, validation, date-time

In my "time off" custom list I have start date and end date. I want to make the user splits up the entries if the time off spans months. In other words if the entry starts Oct 25 and ends Nov 5 I want the user to be prompted to make two entries (one with Oct 25-31) and another with Nov 1-5 instead of allowing the span over two months. Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is a workflow that fires when they add a new item, the other is an Event Handler that fires when they add a new item. Workflows can be built using SharePoint Designer and don't necessarily require programming experience; while Event Handlers are built using Visual Studio and requires quite a bit of programming experience. I know this isn't a complete answer, but at least you know what your options are. I don't think there is an OOTB solution for this.